The existence of polynomials in two variables
Let $p(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ be a polynomial in the variable $x$ with coefficients in the field $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers, and let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{C}$. I would like to ask whether there exist two polynomials $g, h \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ in two variables $x$ and $y$, with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$, such that
$$
g(x,y)(p(x) + p(y) - \lambda_1) + h(x,y)(p(-x) + p(-y) - \lambda_2) = 1.
$$
To investigate this question, I first consider the simple case $p(x) = x^2$. If $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$, the condition reduces to
$$
(g(x,y) + h(x,y))(p(x) + p(y) - \lambda_1) = 1.
$$
At this point, I am unsure how to proceed further.
I would greatly appreciate any insights, counterexamples, or techniques that could assist in answering this question.

I think your example illustrates pretty clearly that the answer is no in general.

We consider your special case $p(x) = x^2$ and $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$.
Let $s(x,y) = g(x,y) + h(x,y)$. Then you require
$$s(x,y)(x^2 + y^2 - \lambda_1) = 1.$$
Taking a complex square root $\zeta$ of $\lambda_1$, we see that $(\zeta,0)$ is a zero of $x^2 + y^2 - \lambda_1$. Clearly $s(\zeta,0) \cdot 0 = 1$ is impossible.
